# Getting started guide for Boost.Spirit?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I've been looking recently at Boost.Spirit (the version included in Boost 1.39), however I'm quite confused from the docs alone. What I'm looking for is for an example of a toy language implemented with Boost.Spirit -- something along the lines of a tiny Javascript or Lua or so, where you basically create an AST and process is. I'd be happy if it just supports function/variable definitions and the basic operators, I just want to see how you would create a normal AST using Boost.Spirit, and how to implement basic rules like identifiers, declarations, etc.

So far, I've tried the calculator example, but it's unclear for me how to implement a larger grammar with Spirit. The mini_c example which is bundled on the other hand looks quite complicated already, and it's not too well documented. Is there some easy to understand guide to Boost.Spirit out there, or a book maybe?

Comment: If you want to learn about the new Boost Spirit X3, I would recommend [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xSBWklPLRvw). The powerpoint slides are found [here](http://ciere.com/cppnow15/using_x3.pdf).

Comment: As an engineering challenge, I've implemented BASIC interpreter using Boost.Spirit X3. It's functional enough to run some text-based games from 80-s and other programs.

https://github.com/black-square/BASIC-boost.spirit

Please take a look if you have a moment. I would be happy to answer any questions or to hear any feedback. 

Also, it's MIT licensed so feel free to use it in any way you want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[An introductory article from CP](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/stl/introduction_spirit.aspx)

[A JSON parser implemented using Boost.Spirit from CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/JSON_Spirit.aspx)

[Spirit Application Repository](http://spirit.sourceforge.net/repository/applications/show_contents.php)

Comment: Here's my own take at JSON using Spirit V2 https://github.com/sehe/spirit-v2-json for comparison

Comment: Here's a nice write-up on Dr. Dobbs: [http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/the-spirit-parser-library-inline-parsing/184401692](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/the-spirit-parser-library-inline-parsing/184401692?pgno=1)

Comment: I suggest the original boost::spirit docs/tutorials: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi_and_karma.html#spirit.qi_and_karma.tutorials.quick_start

Answer (score 8):

The Spirit documentation includes examples and tutorials. 
An example for [generating an AST for a mini XML-like language](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/mini_xml___asts_.html) is included. 
A very useful [overview presentation by Joel de Guzman and Hartmut Kaiser](http://boost-spirit.com/home/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/A_Framework_for_RAD_Spirit.pdf) is also available.

Answer (score 5):

please keep in mind there is a newer boost spirit version with the completely new approach towards generating AST.

Comment: Documentation for Spirit2: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 3):

The book [The Boost C++ Libraries](http://theboostcpplibraries.com/) has a chapter about Spirit which I personally found pretty useful. It's available online, here's a direct link:

[Chapter 11. Boost.Spirit](http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.spirit)

Answer (score 2):

[Using Spirit 2.3: Qi and Karma](http://cierelabs.com/slides/spirit_presentation_v2.pdf)

I think this pdf is quite good for beginners.