# Boost spirit x3 tokenizer with annotation does not work

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I was recently trying to implement a simplest **tokenizer** using *boost spirit x3*. The challenge I'm struggling with right now is retrieving the position of each token in the input stream.

There is a good tutorial about annotation on the official website: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/spirit_x3/tutorials/annotation.html. However, it has some limitations: it basically parses a list of identical(homogeneous) essences, while it is often not really the case in real life.

So I was trying to create the tokenizer with 2 essences: whitespace(sequence of spaces) and a single-line comment (starts with `//`, continues till the end of the line).

See the minimal example code at the end of the question.

However, I'm getting errors while trying to retrieve the position of any of the tokens. After some debugging I discovered that `annotate_position::on_success` handle deduces `T` type to be `boost::spirit::x3::unused_type`, but I don't know why.

So, I have several questions:

1. What am I doing wrong? (I know this is not in style of stackoverflow, but I've been struggling with it for a few days and have no one to consult with). I've been trying to store the actual comment as a string inside `SingleLineComment` and `Whitespace` classes with no success. I suspect that that's because of omitting comment and whitespace strings in parser, is there a way to get around this?
2. What is a best-practice approach for parsing heterogeneous structures?
3. Should I use some specialized libraries for this task (i.e. should use `grammar` class or `spirit::lex`, however there are not such things in **x3** version)
4. Are there some examples of tokenizers (I was looking at [Getting started guide for Boost.Spirit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124232/getting-started-guide-for-boost-spirit), but it is a bit outdated)? As it is for now, I think that docs are not extensive enough to start writing some stuff immediately and I'm considering to write the tokenizer by hands. What was advertised as a simple "get set go" library turned out to be a complex bunch of barely documented templates I don't fully understand.

Here is a minimal example code piece:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <optional>
#include <variant>

#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/support/ast/position_tagged.hpp>

using namespace std;
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

struct position_cache_tag;

// copy paste from boost documentation example
struct annotate_position
{
    template <typename T, typename Iterator, typename Context>
    inline void on_success(Iterator const &first, Iterator const &last, T &ast, Context const &context)
    {
        auto &position_cache = x3::get<position_cache_tag>(context).get();
        position_cache.annotate(ast, first, last);
    }
};

struct SingleLineComment : public x3::position_tagged
{
    // no need to store actual comment string,
    // since it is position tagged and
    // we can then find the corresponding
    // iterators afterwards, is this right?
};
struct Whitespace : public x3::position_tagged
{
    // same reasoning
};
// here can be another token types (e.g. MultilineComment, integer, identifier etc.)

struct Token : public x3::position_tagged
{
    // unites SingleLineComment and Whitespace
    // into a single Token class

    enum class Type
    {
        SingleLineComment,
        Whitespace
    };

    std::optional<Type> type; // type field should be set by semantic action
    // std::optional is kind of reinsurance that type will be set

    std::optional<std::variant<SingleLineComment, Whitespace>> data;
    // same reasoning for std::optional
    // this filed might be needed for more complex
    // tokens, which hold additional data
};

// unique on success hook classes
struct SingleLineCommentHook : public annotate_position
{
};
struct WhitespaceHook : public annotate_position
{
};
struct TokenHook : public annotate_position
{
};

// rules
const x3::rule<SingleLineCommentHook, SingleLineComment> singleLineComment = "single line comment";
const x3::rule<WhitespaceHook, Whitespace> whitespace = "whitespace";
const x3::rule<TokenHook, Token> token = "token";

// rule definitions
const auto singleLineComment_def = x3::lit("//") >> x3::omit[*(x3::char_ - '\n')];
const auto whitespace_def = x3::omit[+x3::ascii::space];

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(singleLineComment, whitespace);

auto _setSingleLineComment = [](const auto &context) {
    x3::_val(context).type = Token::Type::SingleLineComment;
    x3::_val(context).data = x3::_attr(context);
};
auto _setWhitespace = [](const auto &context) {
    x3::_val(context).type = Token::Type::Whitespace;
    x3::_val(context).data = x3::_attr(context);
};

const auto token_def = (singleLineComment[_setSingleLineComment] | whitespace[_setWhitespace]);

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(token);

int main()
{
    // copy paste from boost documentation example
    using iterator_type = std::string::const_iterator;
    using position_cache = boost::spirit::x3::position_cache<std::vector<iterator_type>>;

    std::string content = R"(// first single line comment

// second single line comment

    )";
    // expect 4 tokens: comment -> whitespace -> comment -> whitespace
    position_cache positions{content.cbegin(), content.cend()};

    std::vector<Token> tokens;
    const auto parser = x3::with<position_cache_tag>(std::ref(positions))[*token];

    auto start = content.cbegin();
    auto success = x3::phrase_parse(start, content.cend(), parser, x3::eps(false), tokens);
    success &= (start == content.cend());

    cout << boolalpha << success << endl;
    cout << "Found " << tokens.size() << " tokens" << endl;

    for (auto &token : tokens)
        cout << (token.type.value() == Token::Type::SingleLineComment ? "comment" : "space") << endl;

    // all good till this point

    // now I want to get a position
    // the following throws
    auto pos = positions.position_of(tokens.front());
}
```

Thanks for reading, looking forward to any replies!

Comment: Spirit was never "get set go". It's a productivity _boost_ if you know where the sweet spot lies IMO. Don't feel bad about handwriting tokenizing. Spirit Lex was never very popular, and actually made it hard to keep "the sweet spot" even with Qi. Theoretically it was intended to improve performance by reducing backtracking, but it typically complicates the rules to the extent that it doesn't matter. I'm here if you want any help getting over the initial "head-scratchings". I can also do a quick review to predict whether X3 matches your use-case.

Comment: Just remembered I did some more documentation/digging on error-handling vs position tagging before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61732124/85371.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `on_success` seems to not-happen when semantic actions are involved.

In fact you're redundantly tagging the Ast nodes and the variant.

You could already get the correct result for the first token with e.g.

```
auto pos = positions.position_of(
    std::get<SingleLineComment>(tokens.front().data)));
```

That's obviously not very convenient due to the static type switching required.

Here's a much simplified:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/9G9TMr)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <variant>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/support/ast/position_tagged.hpp>
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

struct SingleLineComment{};
struct Whitespace       {};

using Variant = std::variant<SingleLineComment, Whitespace>;

struct Token : Variant, x3::position_tagged {
    using Variant::Variant;
};

namespace {
    struct position_cache_tag;
    namespace Parser {
        struct annotate_position {
            template <typename T, typename Iterator, typename Context>
                inline void on_success(Iterator first, Iterator last, T &ast, Context const &context) const {
                    auto &position_cache = x3::get<position_cache_tag>(context);
                    position_cache.annotate(ast, first, last);
                }
        };

        // unique on success hook classes
        template <typename> struct Hook {}; // no annotate_position mix-in
        template <> struct Hook<Token> : annotate_position   {};

        template <typename T>
        static auto constexpr as = [](auto p, char const* name = typeid(decltype(p)).name()) {
            return x3::rule<Hook<T>, T> {name} = p;
        };

        // rule definitions
        auto singleLineComment = as<SingleLineComment>("//" >> x3::omit[*(x3::char_ - x3::eol)]);
        auto whitespace        = as<Whitespace>       (x3::omit[+x3::ascii::space]);
        auto token             = as<Token>            (singleLineComment | whitespace, "token");
    }
}

int main() {
    using It             = std::string::const_iterator;
    using position_cache = x3::position_cache<std::vector<It>>;

    std::string const content = R"(// first single line comment

// second single line comment

    )";
    position_cache positions{content.begin(), content.end()};

    auto parser = x3::with<position_cache_tag>(positions)[*Parser::token];

    std::vector<Token> tokens;
    if (parse(begin(content), end(content), parser >> x3::eoi, tokens)) {
        std::cout << "Found " << tokens.size() << " tokens" << std::endl;

        for (auto& token : tokens) {
            auto pos = positions.position_of(token);
            std::cout
                << (token.index() ? "space" : "comment") << "\t"
                << std::quoted(std::string_view(&*pos.begin(), pos.size()))
                << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Found 4 tokens
comment "// first single line comment"
space   "

"
comment "// second single line comment"
space   "

    "
```

Comment: Note the very subtle removal of `std::ref` with `with<>`.That was a quiet improvement (around 1.61?). Luckily, reference semantics are now the default.

Comment: thanks, now I know what's wrong. I saw your other answer on position tagging earlier, but noticed lack of semantic actions and asked again. Thanks for your help and time :)

Comment: I have one more question: is there a need for `as` function instead of manually defining rules for every class? I'm trying to rewrite it in this way and get a compile error, namely `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE undefined for this rule` when compiling `token` rule @sehe

Comment: There's no need for the `as<>`. I'm just "lazy" and prefer things that way. I didn't use BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE anyways. If you want that, you can: [still lazy, of course](https://godbolt.org/z/d4GcdE).

Comment: If you still want to understand why you got "BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE undefined for this rule" we can continue this in chat and you can show the code. Or you can ask antoher question :)